# implementing a notification system

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

http://pastebin.com/Fja8S7nm

In my project, users can post their messages and others can add comment(s) to their posts. I just want them to be notified on such events, so that there is no need for them to check each one of their posts and previous comments to see if there is something new.

Sorry for this generic question but I just want to know "how to implement an appropriate approach for this purpose?"

Comment: What's the question? Do you need us to develop it?

Comment: More questions in the comment than in the actual question. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

Create another table called Notifcations, with a user ID and the text to show to the user. You might also want to add a link to the notification.

When a user comments on a post, just figure out what users should be notified and put their messages in the Notifications table.

Note: don't forget to clean up your Notifications table, as it might grow pretty quick and it's not really something you would like to archive over a very long period (from my point of view).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it helped a lot. at least, now I have something to begin with